# AJAX não passa valores para o PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Código da minha página principal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Salão de Beleza – Madame Nora</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="classes/jquery-2.1.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="classes/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function(){
        $("#btnDesativar").click(function(event) {             
            var aux = confirm('Deseja Realmente Desativar Conta?');
            if(aux == true){                                
                 var acao = "1";
                  var url = "includes/conexaoIndex.php";
                  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
                  xmlHttp.open("POST",url,true);
                  xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  xmlHttp.send("acao="+acao);
            }
        });     
    });     
</script>

</head>
<?php include "/includes/conexaoIndex.php"; ?>
<body>
<form id="loginUsuario" name="loginUsuario" action="" >
 <button type="submit" id="btnDesativar" name="btnDesativar" >Desativar conta</button>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

E na minha outra página, só tenho isso pra testar:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['acao']))
{ 
echo "aqui";}

?>
```

No meu browser fica assim:

```
http://localhost/Projeto/teste.php?btnDesativar=
```

Por que não funciona?

Comment: Bem vindo ao site, micheli. Os tempos de resposta aqui costumam ser extremamente rápidos, mas pedir por urgência é irrelevante. Seu trabalho é fazer um título legal, escrever em português formal, formatar bem a pergunta e descrever o problema com exatidão. Pode [edit] a pergunta sempre que precisar formatar ou esclarecer/adicionar detalhes.

Comment: Se está a usar a framework jQuery porque não aproveita para usar a própria função `$.ajax` para comunicar com o servidor?

Answer (score 1):

Amigo você precisa colocar o &

```
xmlHttp.send("&acao=" + acao);
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a função $.ajax do jQuery e o método serialize() que já formata os dados do formulário para envio. Exemplo:

HTML:

```
<form>
    <!-- Não esquecendo de colocar o atributo 'name', pois é o key value -->
    <input type="text" name="usuario" />
    <input type="password" name="senha" />
    <button type="button">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'arquivo.php',
  data: $('form').serialize(),
  success: function (data) { ... }
});
```

O método serialize() formtaria nesse estilo:

```
usuario=joao&senha=abcdefg
```

Answer (score 0):

Mude o tipo do seu button

```html
<button type="submit" id="btnDesativar" name="btnDesativar" >Desativar conta</button>
```

para

```html
<button type="button" id="btnDesativar" name="btnDesativar" >Desativar conta</button>
```

utilizando o type="submit" ele envia os dados do formulario para o endereço informado no atributo action="..." dentro da tag form (carrega a pagina novamente), quando você não informa algum endereço ele envia para a mesma página. Utilizando o type="button" ele não envia nada, fazendo com que a ação do click seja implementada por você quando chama $("#btnDesativar").click();

Como está utilizando o JQuery recomendo usar o ajax dessa forma utilizando o metodo $.submit() e $.ajax():

[jQUery Submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

[jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```js
$("#loginUsuario").submit(function(event) {
  var aux = confirm('Deseja Realmente Desativar Conta?');
  if (aux == true) {
    var url = "includes/conexaoIndex.php";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: {
        acao: "1"
      },
      success: function(res) {
        console.log(res); //resposta gerada pela pagina requisitada
      }

    });
  }
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="loginUsuario" name="loginUsuario" action="">
  <button type="submit" id="btnDesativar" name="btnDesativar">Desativar conta</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Por que não experimente a função nativa do jQuery + AJAX ?
Segue um exemplo simples:

```
$.ajax({
                url         : 'login.php' , //Caminho do Arquivo PHP
                dataType    : 'json'    , //Tipo de retorno
                data        : { //Enviar dados
                    usuario : 'douglasdreer' ,
                    senha   : 'admin'
                } , // Enviar alguma 
                success : function(result){     //Tratativa de sucesso               
                    //Neste exemplo, vai retornar um TRUE / FALSE;

                    if(result){
                        alert('Logado com sucesso!');
                    } else {
                        alert('Erro ao fazer login, verifique os parâmetros');
                    }
                } ,
                error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ //Tratativa de Erro
                    console.error(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

No PHP

```
$params = $_RESQUEST;
   // Verificações 
   $json = array('status' => TRUE);
   return json_encode($login);
```

Você pode verificar com mais detalhes no site abaixo :

> jQuery Site (ENG):
>   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/